# Godaddy expired domain transfer

Tags: godaddy, domain-registrar, domain-transfer, icann, expired-domains

My domain recently expired on 12/05/2021 and I wanted to transfer it to a new registrar.

So I initiated the transfer.

Unlocked the domain and got the transfer auth key and initiated the transfer at the new registrar after paying the fee.

I then receive an email from GoDaddy saying the following.

> Your domain could not be transferred.
> xyz.com couldn't be transferred
> to another registrar for the following reason:
>
> Express written objection to the transfer from the Transfer Contact. (e.g. - email, fax, paper document or other processes by
> which the Transfer Contact has expressly and voluntarily objected
> through opt-in means).

I then get in touch with GoDaddy support and ask why the transfer was denied, they told me that the domain had expired and that I had to renew it before I could transfer it, I asked them to show me where it said so and they didn't have any documentation to that effect.

I then stated that based on the [ICANN rules](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-holder-faqs-2017-10-10-en#:%7E:text=My%20domain%20name%20has%20just%20expired.%20Can%20my%20registrar%20require%20me%20to%20pay%20for%20a%20renewal%20before%20I%20can%20transfer%20the%20domain%20name%20to%20a%20new%20registrar%3F) stated under the FAQs that under point 11 I can transfer an expired domain.

In any case, I filed a complaint with ICANN regarding this.

However since I received a transfer auth code, does it mean that the transfer will go through?

Comment: Hah!  +1 because I learned that you can transfer an expired domain.

Comment: I'm not sure if GoDaddy reps are trained to say that, or if it's just bad information in their support database... I've successfully transferred domains from them up to 10 days after expiration date (but haven't tried past that yet). As long as you've unlocked the domain and have the authorization code, then initiate the transfer with the other Registrar. Then sign into your GoDaddy account and look for "Transfers Out" and authorize the transfer when it appears there. That usually speeds up the transfer process (in most cases it occurs in just a few minutes).

Comment: So I've done all the transfer out process, however there's nothing under the Godaddy account "transfers out", matter of fact I don't even have a menu option like that under domains.

Comment: See [this](https://www.godaddy.com/help/check-the-status-of-my-domain-transfer-23875).

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out.

You need to turn off the "domain protection" plan.

GoDaddy has a domain protection plan to protect privacy etc. Now when the domain expires you can't downgrade/turn off the domain protection plan unless you renew the DOMAIN and the domain protection plan, you can can get a refund on the domain protection plan once you renew it and then turn it off, but in the process forces you to renew the domain itself on which you obviously don't get a refund. They don't allow you to just renew the domain protection plan and not the domain.